# JQuery Mobile - White screen between transitions

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Am using Samsung Galaxy Phone with `Android 4.1` Version. Am seeing white screen between page tranistion. `JQM Version is : 1.3.1`. Already doing the following as per other suggestions:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "none";
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
});
```

But, does not seem to work. This is more evident when we come back from another page. Would appreciate valuable suggestions and fix.

Comment: A lot of thing can cause this problem so you will need to be more specific about the design of your up. Do you have a working example we can test?

Comment: No dont have any working example. am doing this as part of my site implementation.Am using single page templates and loading the site. If you can ask me specific questions, would let you know.

Comment: How do you perform the page transitions (through Ajax)? Make sure that you are not explicitly using transitions which require 3D transform support. By default, all transitions except fade require 3D transform support. Also check that the mobileinit handler is located between jQuery js and jQuery Mobile js.

Comment: Thanks you are correct. The mobileinit was not getting executed, since it was not between jQuery js and jQuery Mobile js. But, removing the transition removes the app like feel too. Are these bugs going to be fixed in JQM soon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the mobileinit handler is located between jQuery js and jQuery Mobile js.

Furthermore as mentioned in [jQM 1.3.1 Docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/transitions/):

> Important: Some platforms currently have issues with transitions. We are working on a solution to solve the problem for everyone. If you are experiencing flickers and flashes during or at the end of a transition we suggest the following workaround. Please note that this workaround should be thoroughly tested on the target platform before deployment. This workaround is known to cause performance issues and browser crashes on some platforms, especially Android. Add the following code to your custom css.

`.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }`

> Only seeing fade transitions? To view all transition types, you must be on a browser that supports 3D transforms. By default, devices that lack 3D support (such as Android 2.x) will fallback to "fade" for all transition types.