# jQuery .show() if class="visible" for JQM app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What I am trying to accomplish is to have the non-active pages default display="none;" but be visible (possibly using .show()) when the page is active.

I am trying to accomplish this because (after many many many hours) of trying different suggestions cannot eliminate the white flash that occurs when slide transitioning to a new page. One suggestion was to hide all non-active pages until they are active.

```
<div data-role="page" style="display:none;" id="page2">
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870713/jquery-mobile-white-screen-between-transitions

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have tried that as well and it did not solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will solve your white flash problem, but here is how to hide and show page divs:  [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hSaE7/1/)

I created a class with `visibility:hidden;` and applied it to the invisible page(s) in markup:

```
.hidePage {
    visibility:hidden;
}

<div data-role="page" id="page2" class="hidePage">...
<div data-role="page" id="page3" class="hidePage">...
```

Then I handle the `pageshow` event for all pages and remove or add the class depending which one is now shown:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(e){    
    var curPageID = $(e.target).prop("id");
    $('[data-role="page"]').each(function( index ) {
        if ($(this).prop("id") == curPageID){
            $(this).removeClass("hidePage");
        } else {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("hidePage")){  
                $(this).addClass("hidePage");    
            }
        }    
    });
});
```

If you still get the flash, we could try a setTimeout and delay the visibility by a few milliseconds...

Comment: Hm...when I implement the js into the header in-between the jquery and jquery mobile scripts it loads the initial screen but becomes "static" per say. No content is selectable to move to the next page. When I implement the script after loading both jquery and jquery mobile the script fires however the pages stay hidden.

Comment: I usually put the scripts right before the closing tag of the body, after all other markup.  Can you tell if it is adding/removing the class?

Comment: Well when moving the script to the body I get the same result. I know that the class is changing because when I navigate, the next page is hidden. Thanks for your help also!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution!

I implemented fastclick.js found here: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.

I simply added

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    });
</script>
```

to the head of my document.

No more flash/flicker when navigating between pages.

I hope this helps the many others I have seen with the flickering effect.